# Displaying Tweets from CPT

Tags: twitter

I have a content aggregation website coming online, and have setup a CPT that is being populated with Twitter search results through WP RSS Aggregator.

The permalink for each post is the URL to the tweet. I know WordPress will parse links to tweet and format them for display.

How can I loop these permalinks and have WP process them? Every plugin I’ve tried only pulls from Twitter, and won’t pull from a CPT. I can loop them with php or Custom Content Shortcode plugin, but they don't get parsed by WP.

Comment: the concept of pulling doesn't really apply here. What you're describing where WP turns a URL into an embed, is called oembed

Comment: That was extremely helpful...actually resolved it with that input. I'm using Custom Content Shortcode to more easily create loops (lamer, I know), and it had an embed attribute.

Comment: If you can write an answer below for others who have the same issue that'd be awesome

Comment: In this case I'm using a plugin called Custom Content Shortcode to create loops on various pages. For Twitter, YouTybe, etc, you just need to use embed=true in your content tag. I'm sure this is doable in php as well; this is what my loop looks like with that plugin:  
  
    <div class="fa-container">  
    [loop type=tweets count=3]  
    <div class="fa-content">  
    [if type=tweets]  
    [field url embed=true]  
    [/if]  
    </div>  
    [if not last]<div style="display:inline-block;width:3%;"></div>[/if]  
    [/loop]  
</div>

Comment: No idea why my above post looks like that; I followed the commenting format.

Comment: You have to use backticks, comments are always single line, so you can't use embed stuff. If you need to add code to your question, you should add it to your question via the edit link, not the comments. You should also post answers as answers, if you scroll down there's a box to enter an answer in